# Proving some properties about the expected first order statistic (maximum) with respect to sample size.

Tags: integration, statistics, normal-distribution, order-statistics

**Question:**
Consider $n$ random variables $x_1, x_2,\cdots x_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. The expected value of the $i$th order statistic (the maximum) can be written as

$E(\mathcal{O}^n_1)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}nx\Phi(x)^{n-1}\phi(x)\:dx$.

I wish to show that for $n_1<n_2<n_3$,

$E(\mathcal{O}^{n1}_1)<E(\mathcal{O}^{n2}_1)<E(\mathcal{O}^{n3}_1)$, and

$E(\mathcal{O}^{n3}_1)-E(\mathcal{O}^{n2}_1<E(\mathcal{O}^{n2}_1-E(\mathcal{O}^{n1}_1)$,

where $\mathcal{O}^{n1}_1$ is the first order statistic (maximum) for a sample of $n1$.

**Progress so far**
I've managed to prove the part for first-order derivative by invoking the concept of first-order stochastic dominance. But still no progress on the second-order...

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first inequality, you could (prove and) use the identity $$E(\mathcal O^n)=\int_\mathbb R(\mathbf 1_{x\gt0}-\Phi(x)^n)\,\mathrm dx,$$
and the fact that, for every $x$, the sequence $(\Phi(x)^n)$ is decreasing. (*Hint:* Start from the identity in your post and integrate by parts, using the functions $u=x$ and $v=\Phi(x)^n$.)

The second inequality cannot hold in full generality since $\mathcal O^n\to+\infty$ almost surely when $n\to\infty$, hence the limit of the inequality when $n_3\to\infty$, $n_1$ and $n_2$ fixed, is absurd.